# How to draw geometries that always stay inside the canvas?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use p5.js to create geometries.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  noStroke();
  beginShape();
  let a = random(-100, 100);
  vertex(30, a);
  vertex(100, 100);
  vertex(-30, 800);
  vertex(300, 300);
  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Everything should stay inside the canvas. How is it possible to do that?

Comment: Can you draw what you spec if everything is fulfilled correctly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put an answer at the bottom, but I'm going to give some hints before:

There are built-in variables for the width and height of the canvas, named `width` and `height`, respectively.

All of the pixels on the canvas have positive coordinates. So for any vertex of the shape, if either coordinate is negative, it will be off the screen.

The `setup()` block is executed once at the beginning, and the `draw()` block is executed every single frame. Since `random()` gives you a different value every time it is called, you can't call it every frame if you want the shape to stay the same for every frame.

I recommend learning about arrays and loops: [while loop](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/while), [for loop](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/for), [arrays](https://youtu.be/VIQoUghHSxU)

If you want the shape to not cross over itself, that is much more complicated. It is doable, so go ahead and comment on this answer or edit your question if that's what you're looking for.

I think this might do what you want:

```
let vertices = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  let numberOfVertices = random(3, 11); //pick the number of points
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
    vertices.push(createVector(random(width), random(height))); //add a point to the list of points
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  noStroke();
  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    vertex(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y);//place each vertex
  }
  endShape();
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you sooo much! Yes, it would be great to avoid the crossing. I created this article for that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67284791/12501851 – Would be very thankful if you could help me again!

Comment: Someone else beat me to it by about an hour, but they did almost exactly what I had in mind (their answer is probably better)